# XSSFSheet.protectSheet is not working in Server

Tags: java, excel

I need to protect an excel sheet during Runtime. When running the code from eclipse its working fine, but the same code when deployed in Server is throwing the below exception:

org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.protectSheet(Ljava/lang/String;)V

The code which I am using to Protect sheet:

```
    try{

         String password = "password";
         sheet.protectSheet(password); //{Failing here in server}
         unlockedCellStyle = EsiliconUtils.workbook.createCellStyle();
         unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That's not an exception, that's a method signature.

Comment: well .. ok but what is going wrong here? Its is working fine from Eclipse

Comment: Even logs are not getting captured ...

Comment: That was meant as a subtle hint for you to post the actual stacktrace. Your problem might be in the classloader. Or perhaps you didn't deploy the apache poi classes to your server causing a ClassNotFoundException at runtime. But I'm merely speculating since you never posted your stacktrace.